# How to create a custom validator for FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I have a formGroup object with 6 fields. 5 fields out of the 6 are collectively mandatory, meaning either one of them has to have a value for it to be a valid form. It does not matter which one of the 5 fields has a value as long as one of them has a value. How can I add a custom validator for the form?

Answer (score 0):

Here is two ways from my point of view:

1. Custom `@Directive` that would implement `Validator` and has entire logic inside it. Then you would can use it as validation directive on the form elements (and button's).

Good example could be found there: [LINK](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/advanced-topics/basic-custom-validators/)

2. Or, not so cure solution but if you need it just on one component (without re-usability) just implement method inside the component with the checks of the input values and based on result do your logic to display error messages or anything you need for your project.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using 2 way binding with template driven forms.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
      ...
      <input name="input1" [(ngModel)]="input1" [required]="!checkIfValueExists()"/>          
      <input name="input2" [(ngModel)]="input2" [required]="!checkIfValueExists()"/>     
      <input name="input3" [(ngModel)]="input3" [required]="!checkIfValueExists()"/>     

  `
})
export class MyComponent {
    input1: string;
    input2: string;
    input3: string;

    constructor() {}

    checkIfValueExists(): boolean {
        return input1 || input2 || input3;
    }
}
```